# Capitalizing without downcasing string in python

Tags: python, capitalization

I am looking for a function to force the upper case of the first character of my string but without modifying the case of the following characters.

```py
>>> print('FRANCE'.capitalize()+' while wished answer will be "FRANCE"')
France while wished answer will be "FRANCE"
>>> print('franCE'.capitalize()+' while wished answer will be "FranCE"')
France while wished answer will be "FranCE"
```

Of course, I know that I can to it by manipulating first character directly.

EDIT: But manipulating first character means you've check that it exists which makes the code too complicated than I was looking for.

Comment: `s = 'franCE'`, `print(s[0].upper() + s[1:])` -> 'FranCE'

Comment: If you know how to do it, what are you expecting from this question?

Comment: I was looking for a function/parameters...

Comment: Why don't you try writing a function that does what you want? If you get stuck with that, someone will probably be able to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = 'franCE'
print(s[0].upper() + s[1:])
```

Comment: You assume that the string has at least 2 characters... This is not wanted and that's why I am looking for a builting function

Comment: You mean that `s = ''` -> `''`. You should update your question to say so.

Comment: @Sigmun This code only assumes that the string has at least _one_ character.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for a function like this:

```
def upper_first(s):
    return s[0].upper() + s[1:] if s else s
```

(Shamelessly stolen from Paras jain)

Comment: You can even shortcut that with `return s and s[0].upper() + s[1:]`